# Create list in R with the names and values coming from another list

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

So the question is formunlated really badly, but what I want to achieve is the following: I have the following list:

```
list(a = data.frame(foo=1:10, bar=11:20), b = data.frame(foo=1:10, bar=11:20))
```

what I now want to create is another list that has the content as:

```
(list(a=c("foo", "bar"), b=c("foo", "bar")))
$a
[1] "foo" "bar"

$b
[1] "foo" "bar"
```

But obviously I don't want to hardcode it. I guess there is some more or less easy answer, but I just can't think of any at the moment. Named list and assigning names to objects still confuses me a lot in R. So any help would be super appreciated:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your original list is "l", you can do:

```
lapply(l, names)
# $a
# [1] "foo" "bar"
# 
# $b
# [1] "foo" "bar"
```

From `?names`, you get the description: "Functions to get or set the names of an object."

The names of the `data.frame`s in your original list are extracted with this, and `lapply` preserves the names of the original list.

Comment: thanks a lot! Knew there would be an easy answer! Sorry only a quick follow up question: Why does this work? What is the function of `names` in this context?

Comment: @RobinKohrs, let me know if my explanation edited into the answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
map(l, names)
```

-output

```
#$a
#[1] "foo" "bar"

#$b
#[1] "foo" "bar"
```